# Creating DataTable variable without explicitly referencing to the DataSet

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I want to know how to create DataTable variable without explicitly referencing to the DataSet. For example I have this working example:

```
UsersDataSet.AddressDataTable address;
```

I would like to omit the UsersDataSet part, because It is being repeated numerous times in the code. I tried to define it with using:

```
using ManagingUsers.UsersDataSetTableAdapters;
```

But it still would not recognize AddressDataTable without UsersDataSet:

```
AddressDataTable address;
```

It says that the type or namespace name could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using AddressDataTable = UsersDataSet.AddressDataTable ;
```

should do the trick

More info on using [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes that is is. Just minor change, it has to be: using AddressDataTable = ManagingUsers.UsersDataSet.AddressDataTable;